# Connecting to remote virtual machine using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, ubuntu, client-server, serversocket

I am trying to connect to a virtual machine using sockets in Java. I have my client and server applications working with no issues on localhost. When I run the Server code and try to connect from a separate machine with the IP address and port number, my client connection times out.

Here is a link to my virtual machine network settings page https://wiki.redbrick.dcu.ie/mw/RBVM_Networking

Do I need to specify any particular parameters in Java to make my server accept connections? Is this an issue I have to take up with the VM network admins?

Any suggestions would be appreciated !

p.s I am running ubuntu server and can access phpmyadmin remotely with no problems.

**Edit**

I have run nmap and the port I am using for the server side application shows up as open.

Comment: Have you tried poking it via telnet to see if the sever is available?

Comment: Maybe your hosting provider only allows common ports through (80, 21, 22, 8080)?

Comment: Is your server binding to localhost or to it's public ip?

Comment: The server only requires the port number on which to listen to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My provider was blocking all but a select few ports, got a list of open ones and now it works. derp!